# segmentation fault (core dumped) problem when trying to open xgterm for IRAF

Tags: segmentation-fault, coredump, iraf

I have run into an issue opening xgterm. In my terminal, I did the usual conda activate iraf27, then xgterm &, and then I get a message: Segmentation fault (core dumped) xgterm
I am not sure how to go about fixing this problem

I have tried conda clean -a and that did not change anything. I have reinstalled the iraf environment and am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you specify which operating system and architecture you use? f.e. conda/iraf27 is not working anymore on newer macs because there is no 32-bit support.

Comment: Just updated to Fedora 38

Comment: I could imagine that the newest Fedora also just does not support 32-bit apps like Conda's IRAF. You may try out the one from https://iraf-community.github.io .